# What does the filtered column of a EXPLAIN'ed query mean in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = 1 LIMIT 10;
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+--------------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref   | rows   | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+--------------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table    | ref  | column        | column       | 1       | const | 341878 |   100.00 |       |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+--------------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

What does the filtered column mean, and should the number be high or low?  Yes, I've read the docs, but I don't quite understand what the number indicates or what values are considered desirable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `filtered` column is an estimated percentage that specifies the number of rows that will be joined with the previous table. In your case it's `100%`, i.e. all rows.

The `rows`, as you presumably know, is an estimation of the number of rows examined by the query, so `rows x filtered / 100` will be the number of joins that have to be made (the number of rows left after applying the table condition).

For additional info, see [What's New in MySQL Optimizer - What's new in MySQL Query Optimizer](http://forge.mysql.com/w/images/9/90/WhatsNewInMySQLOptimizer.pdf) (slide 10).

**EDIT:**

There is an Appendix in the [High performance MySQL (2nd edition)](http://books.google.com/books?id=BL0NNoFPuAQC&lpg=PP1&ots=CNWRuqwAaV&dq=high%20performance%20mysql%20second%20edition&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=high%20performance%20mysql%20second%20edition&f=false) book which suggests that *the optimizer currently uses this estimate (`filtered`) only for the `ALL`, `index`, `range` and `index_merge` access methods*.